# need help fitting an img into a div which is getting bigger every time

Tags: html, css

as you can observe in this page http://arielnavarro.esy.es/ , which I use to train, have a slight issue I dont like. As you can see the nav bar is bigger than the buttons and that only happened when I added the facebook logo, and the linkedin logo. I've tried to play with the height of both images but I end up with the saize of the nav bar changing as well.

below are the codes from css and html

```css
@charset "utf-8";
.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.active { 
    color: white;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#fb {
 float:right;
 margin: 0 auto;
 z-index: 2;
 padding-right:15px;
}
#linkedin {
 float:right;
 z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <title>Documento sin título</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div>
     <ul class="navbar">
      <li id="home"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li id="quienes_soy"><a href="#quienes_soy">quienes soy</a></li>
      <li id="contacto"><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
    <li id="about"><a href="#acerca_de">acerca de</a></li>
          <a id="linkedin" target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ariel-navarro-297062129/"><img src= "http://i.imgur.com/15FuoKO.png" height="45"></a>
      <a id="fb" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/ariel.navarro.9655"><img src= "http://i.imgur.com/w3S3D0o.png" ></a>
         </ul> 
        </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

thank you all :)

Comment: you could do something like this that just sets the images as BACKGROUND images using a css class, and have their size and position be dynamic... this was just a really quick example I threw together based on your code.  So this doesn't use IMG tags, but rather the link tags are assigned a class that has height / width set and the background image properties to show the correct images.     https://jsfiddle.net/1utkshef/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your 'navbar' a fixed height. That should get you moving in the right direction.